# accessing map property from .properties file in application context (Spring)

Tags: java, spring

In my .properties file I have something like this:

```
map = key1=value1, key2=value2
```

How do I access the key-value pairs in my applicationContext.xml using placeholders? I know that if the property were just a string it would simply be:

```
<bean id="string_prop" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${string.prop}"/>
</bean>
```

I've also seen this:

```
<util:map id="map_prop" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <entry key="key" value="value"></entry>
</util:map>
```

But I'm not sure how to access the key-value pairs from the .properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the map in java code means use like below,

In applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="mapName" class="java.util.HashMap">
        <constructor-arg ref="property" /> 
</bean>

<util:properties id="property" location="properName.properties"/>
```

In java:

```
 @Autowired
    protected HashMap<String, String> mapName;
```

Comment: Hi. I did that but then the mapName hashmap was populated with everything in the properties file, not just the mapName property.

Comment: to get the values, use as mapName.get("key"); key is your "string.prop".

Answer (score 0):

If you want from applicationContext itself means use like below,

In applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="propertyName.properties"/>
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="string_prop" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${string.prop}"/>
</bean>
```

In properties file:

```
string.prop=some name
```